# Using BreezeSharp as a SQLite.Net replacement in Xamarin.*?

Tags: xamarin, breeze, breeze-sharp, sqlite.net

How successful and pleasant would it be if I used only BreezeSharp for data management in a Mobile App?  With the ability to export/save/import locally, I could imagine a scenario where I pull from the server and then work mostly in the EntityManager cache.

The question of how much the cache holds, and how it deals with overflow come to mind.   I also wonder if I would end up writing a lot of code to manage exported entities if the cache doesn't have a disk-based overflow mechanism.

Comment: What is **the question** here?

Comment: The first sentence.  I'm asking broadly for experiences or opinions about what will and won't work using BreezeSharp as my only data management technology on Xamarin as compared to the more traditional SQLite approach.  If its feasible, I've imagined that the cache is possibly the limiting factor and I've outlined an additional question about how the cache handles overflow.

Comment: Then you're asking for opinions?

Comment: I seek authoritative, informed, specific information, preferably from the BreezeSharp authors or users that have considered or are using it instead of a standard SQLite database on mobile clients.  Since I don't know all of the specific problems I might encounter (hence posting here) I asked a broad question and a specific one regarding cache management to get the conversation started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is in-memory only, so it is limited to the amount of memory on your mobile device.  That said, this is typically enough for 10's of thousands of entities on even pretty limited devices. Not sure I would go down the route of an overflow mechanism, other than simply detaching entities from the cache, letting the garbage collector clean them, and just go back to the server for any entities not in the cache.